# UR5e + ROS Melodic + MoveIt best setup for Inverse Kinematics

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using the robot to open a drawer through a Python program, and for doing this I am using a lot of points for the eef to reach every time using IK of MoveIt.

But mostly of the times the controller and planner fails (with Aborted message) and this entails to the failure or mostly to collision behaviours.

I am using the default setup of universal robots repo (calibration-devel branch of fmauch) and the ur_robot_driver (melodic branch) of Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver.
As I have an attached gripper, I modified only the ur_macro.xacro file for translating the tool0 link with 0.18 on x-axis wrt flange.

Did I something wrong?? Can you suggest me any better setup, as controller/planner or ik-solver for this problem??

Thank you very much!! I would appreciate a lot your help!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402489/ur5e-+-ros-melodic-+-moveit-best-setup-for-inverse-kinematics/) by [francirrapi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105419/francirrapi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-18**:
Which ik solver are you using now?

If anything source-based (ie: IKFast or handwritten): don't change the URDF, as it's likely you won't update the code, leading to the IK solver no longer corresponding (ie: matching) to your URDF.

Regardless of which IK solver:

> I modified only the ur_macro.xacro file for translating the tool0 link with 0.18 on x-axis wrt flange.

Don't change `tool0`. That's not how it's supposed to work.

`tool0` is used to represent an *unconfigured tool frame* (ie: all zeros). By definition if you change it, it cannot be `tool0` any more.

Define a new frame, give it a proper name and use *that* as your tool frame.

**Comment by [francirrapi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105419/francirrapi/) on 2022-06-18**:
Thank you very much @gvdhoorn for your answer!!
Now I am using the default KDL solver, I tried some time ago even Trak-IK but did not solve the problem.
Ah perfect now I understand. So in this case, as I am using KDL I can change the URDF, but not the `tool0` link right?

And so for defining a new frame, I have to define it at the end of ur_macro.xacro in the same way as tool0 is defined??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-18**:
Both KDL and TracIK are able to deal with runtime defined chains, so there shouldn't be an issue with updating your URDF/XACRO.

> And so for defining a new frame, I have to define it at the end of ur_macro.xacro in the same way as tool0 is defined??

personally I would not edit anything in files in `ur_description` at all. Consider those read-only.

Adding EEF or additional frames can be done in a `.xacro` of your own, in your own package. See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages#Example:_adding_an_end-effector_to_a_robot) for an example.

**Comment by [francirrapi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105419/francirrapi/) on 2022-06-19**:
Perfect, so after the creation of this new `.xacro` file, with the merge of robot and gripper, I have to create a new moveit configuration with moveit setup assistant if I understood right, with the chain of robot group same as before, and the chain of gripper from his base link to which link exactly? (as it is a two finger gripper)
And also, after the creation of the moveit config, which would be in this case the frame that the IK will use as EEF? (as before was the tool0 frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by creating a new `.xacro` file including all macros of robot and gripper where I also added a new frame for the EEF attached to the flange link of the robot and then creating a new moveit config through moveit setup assistant. Thank you very much!!

---

Originally posted by [francirrapi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105419/francirrapi/) with karma: 18 on 2022-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0